# After ubuntu install + software raid 0 config, we see: rejecting I/O to offline device

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, software-raid, syslog

I'm trying to pin down what this error `rejecting I/O to offline device` is, as seen towards the end of this syslog.

Ideas:

- Problem with RAID-0 configuration (we have 2 4TB disks in RAID-0 and I do see a warning about it)
- Virtual CD - there is no CD on this server, but I did have a virtual CD attached over an IPMI/KVM tool for the installation. That should not be attached now though, but I see some messages about it.

Other than the above notes, this is a new installation of ubuntu 12.04 that was done over netboot and via the IPMI/KVM console.

```
Apr 12 19:42:46 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Apr 12 19:42:46 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.1.5.255 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Apr 12 19:42:46 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 10.1.5.255 from 10.1.0.1
Apr 12 19:42:46 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPOFFER from 10.1.3.48 rejected by rule 10.1.3.48 mask 255.255.255.255.
Apr 12 19:42:46 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPACK of 10.1.5.255 from 10.1.0.1
Apr 12 19:42:46 ubuntu dhclient: bound to 10.1.5.255 -- renewal in 43104 seconds.
Apr 12 19:42:46 ubuntu kernel: [    8.512887] init: failsafe main process (745) killed by TERM signal
Apr 12 19:42:46 ubuntu kernel: [    8.551401] type=1400 audit(1365820966.336:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=866 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 12 19:42:46 ubuntu kernel: [    8.552253] type=1400 audit(1365820966.340:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=866 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 12 19:42:46 ubuntu kernel: [    8.552723] type=1400 audit(1365820966.340:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=866 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 12 19:42:46 ubuntu kernel: [    8.562192] type=1400 audit(1365820966.348:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=868 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 12 19:42:46 ubuntu cron[895]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Apr 12 19:42:46 ubuntu mdadm[910]: DeviceDisappeared event detected on md device /dev/md/0, component device Wrong-Level
Apr 12 19:42:46 ubuntu cron[920]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
Apr 12 19:42:46 ubuntu cron[920]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Apr 12 19:42:54 ubuntu ntpdate[818]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset 0.188979 sec
Apr 12 19:42:56 ubuntu kernel: [   18.721994] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
Apr 12 19:43:12 ubuntu kernel: [   35.070907] usb 1-5.3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
Apr 12 19:43:23 ubuntu kernel: [   45.212938] usb 1-5.3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
Apr 12 19:43:39 ubuntu kernel: [   61.354018] usb 1-5.3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
Apr 12 19:43:39 ubuntu kernel: [   61.521613] usb 1-5.3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
Apr 12 19:43:49 ubuntu kernel: [   71.663780] usb 1-5.3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
Apr 12 19:43:49 ubuntu kernel: [   71.756135] sr 6:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Apr 12 19:43:49 ubuntu kernel: [   71.756166] sr 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 12 19:43:49 ubuntu kernel: [   71.756722] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x caddy
Apr 12 19:43:49 ubuntu kernel: [   71.756726] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
Apr 12 19:43:49 ubuntu kernel: [   71.756951] sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
Apr 12 19:43:49 ubuntu kernel: [   71.757034] sr 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 12 19:43:49 ubuntu kernel: [   71.757643] sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
Apr 12 19:43:49 ubuntu kernel: [   71.778813] sr 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 12 19:43:49 ubuntu kernel: [   71.779394] sr 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 12 19:43:49 ubuntu kernel: [   71.779972] sr 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 12 19:43:49 ubuntu kernel: [   71.780829] sr 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
```

---

**Update:**

@jordanm & others - correct, I just confirmed that this is the CDROM device, but this is a "virtual cd" that was created by a previous KVM session via IPMI on the server. It doesn't exist any more, any idea how can I get rid of it?  Or not attempt to access it, I'm not sure why it's there.

Comment: The offline device is the CDROM.